# how to update shape (not geometry) in three.js?

Tags: three.js

I am trying to customize a shape by a slider, and then the shape is extruded by ExtrudeGeometry. First, I created 4 points as in "pts", and then created a "shape" with them, and finally, created a geomtery by extrude it through a line. However, I cannot make it works. My HTML code is as below:

```
<head>


<script src="three.min.js"> </script>
<script src="three.js"> </script>


<script src="TrackballControls.js"></script>
<script src="main.js"> </script>
</head>


<body onload="start()">
<div id="s"> </div>
</body>

</html>
```

and the "main" js file is as follows:

```
var camera, scene, renderer, phone, material, mesh;
var shape, extrudeSettings, randomSpline, controls;
var pts = [];
var randomPoints = [];
var v;
function start() {

scene = new THREE.Scene();
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75,window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight,1,10000);
camera.position.set( 0, 0, 500 );
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setClearColor( 0x222222 );
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
controls = new THREE.TrackballControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
                controls.minDistance = 100;
                controls.maxDistance = 600;

scene.add(camera);
pts.push( new THREE.Vector3 (100,1,0));
pts.push( new THREE.Vector3 (-100,1,0));
pts.push( new THREE.Vector3 (-100,-1,0));
pts.push( new THREE.Vector3 (100,-1,0));

randomPoints.push( new THREE.Vector3 (0,0,10));
randomPoints.push( new THREE.Vector3 (0,0,-10));

randomSpline =  new THREE.SplineCurve3( randomPoints );
extrudeSettings = {
                    steps           : 200,
                    bevelEnabled    : false,
                    extrudePath     : randomSpline
                };
shape = new THREE.Shape(pts);

phone = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry(shape, extrudeSettings);

material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0x0000FF, wireframe:true});
mesh = new THREE.Mesh(phone,material);
scene.add(mesh);

var slider = document.createElement("input");
slider.setAttribute("type", "range");
slider.setAttribute("value", 90);
slider.setAttribute("id", "sliding");

document.getElementById("s").appendChild(slider);

document.getElementById("s").style.position = "absolute";
document.getElementById("s").style.zIndex="1";


animate();
}
function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    v = document.getElementById("sliding").value;
    pts[0].x = v;
    pts[1].x = -v;
    pts[2].x = -v;
    pts[3].x = v;

    shape.needsUpdate = true;
    phone.verticesNeedUpdate = true;


    phone.dynamic=true;

    controls.update();
renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you create an `ExtrudeGeometry`, it creates the geometry based on the parameter, but it doesn't store the object you created it from. You'll need to create a `new ExtrudeGeometry` each time you want to update it, or you may be able to simply adjust `phone.scale`, depending on your needs.

Comment: I'm trying to update the verticies of it but when modifying the verticies of the geometry itself it is very slow. it is made with beizercurves is theere a wway just to move those curves to update it? doesnt have to be extruded

Comment: @B''HBi'ezras--BoruchHashem You should post a new question, and give context for the overall effect you want to achieve, and the code you've got so far. Feel free to link to it here.